# How to display the large table without breaking in the dompdf while Generating the Pdf

Tags: php, css, dompdf

I have Generated the PDF file for the For the Following table using the DOMPDF. But while generating the pdf its only showing the First 15 rows of the table.

**Note:** I have used the style in tables page-break-inside: avoid;

```
i have attached the HTML coding of the table in the fiddle.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o4ga8uze/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In relation to your document the main advice I can give is to get rid of the wrapper table. If any particular table cell exceeds the page size you'll run into a fairly nasty [bug](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/98). Luckily for your document you do not need that outer table since all it's doing is wrapping your actual content to provide spacing.

Instead of this:

```
<table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:5px;  page-break-inside: avoid;" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th class="head">Heading</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid; page-break-inside: avoid;" class="border-top border-left border-right border-bottom">
      <!-- invoice table -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Try this:

```
<div style="margin:5px;">
  <div class="head">Heading</div>
  <div style="border:1px solid;" class="border-top border-left border-right border-bottom">
    <!-- invoice table -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o4ga8uze/1/

As far as preventing the table from paging...
You don't include an actual reference to all your stylesheets so it's difficult to provide much guidance. The first thing I can say is that since your table is all that's on the page (at least in your sample) it would have to have a low enough number of rows to not require paging.

I notice that your reference Bootstrap 2.3.2 so I'll also note that [dompdf doesn't work all that well with bootstrap](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/631) at this time. You might try setting a high enough DPI such that dompdf is able to fit more of the content on the page.

- In v0.6.2 or earlier set the `DOMPDF_DPI` configuration constant to, for example, 300.
- In v0.7.0 set the option after instantiating dompdf: `$dompdf->set_option('dpi', 300);`

Finally, drop the `page-break-inside: avoid;` styling. This can be particularly problematic with content that exceeds the page size, particularly tables.